# Software installation Solus-Project

Tags: linux, bash, pygtk, package-managers, solus

I am currently running Solus Linux on my PC, and like many running it, have found the greatest difficulty with it to be software installation. Solus comes packaged **Natively** with a package manager called eopkg, but has a very limited selection of software. There apparently is a way to install software from source i.e. tar.gz archives, by extracting and compiling the source. With this in mind, I began developing a package manager for Solus that would automatically install such programs from source. After extensive searching however, I have been unable to find any clear coverall answers to the steps in compiling and installing the sources.

**My Question:**
**What are the steps for extracting, compiling, and installing programs on Solus or possibly general linux?**

Please note that this is my first time using any form of linux besides Kali For Soc. Engineering, so the answer may apply to most distros on top of Solus and I may be an idiot.

I appreciate all answers and forms of help, and I thank you in advance as well for any help you do provide. Thanks!

**Note: I will accept links to instructions or similar questions should they exist. Thanks!**

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming? This looks like just a Linux question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start with the [Solus documentation](https://solus-project.com/help-center/home/), and looking around `eopkg list-available` before asserting it has no software (it has thousands of packages).

Also note there is a [package request process](https://solus-project.com/articles/packaging/request-a-package/en/), again, part of the documentation. You'll also want to make sure you have the [base development tools](https://solus-project.com/articles/package-management/basics/en/#base-development-tools) installed before compiling anything:

```
sudo eopkg it -c system.devel
```

> that would automatically install such programs from source

We already have [ypkg](https://github.com/solus-project/ypkg) and [solbuild](https://github.com/solus-project/solbuild) for building packages in a native fashion, and an incredibly simple contribution process to get your own packages in the repositories and in a binary form for all users to enjoy.

My fear is you're reinventing things that Solus *already has*, and my supsicion is that you're trying to build something like the AUR. If that is the case, you should look into how Solus [packaging works](https://solus-project.com/articles/packaging/guide/en/) and rely on solbuild for clean chroot builds (along with [local repositories](https://solus-project.com/articles/packaging/local-repository/en/).)

Comment: Thank you so much, this was just what I needed!

Comment: ps. I did not mean it had none exactly, but some I needed weren't there.

Comment: That's fine :) Hit us up on IRC (#Solus-Dev on freenode) if you wanna discuss your project further. Daytimes GMT :)